# Does Objective-C guarantee the initialization of interface member data?

Tags: objective-c

In an interface such as this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    bool PlainOldBool;
}

@end
```

... does `PlainOldBool` get auto-initialized to false, or is it necessary to use an init method to do that explicitly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes ([unless your `false` is not 0](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)). The default `+alloc`/`+allocWithZone:` method will automatically zero out all ivars.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW17

> - It initializes all other instance variables to zero (or to the equivalent type for zero, such as `nil`, `NULL`, and `0.0`).

Comment: You may want to update the link you have there to the +alloc method on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

Also worth noting is that if you're doing  Objective-C++, C++ objects that are ivars of Objective-C objects are not initalized : their constructors are not called by default.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty important to know!  So what do you do, a bunch of placement new() operators?

Comment: Actually I was wrong: by default, the constructors are called. There is a build setting to control that, it's objc-call-cxx-cdtors. If you leave it checked, the "default" ctors (e.g. the ones with no argument) will be called.

More details on the gcc manual :
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Objective_002dC-and-Objective_002dC_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html


(Or you can use pointers and call new() manually)