# Auto-initialization of object variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In Objective C on iOS, are instance variables of object reference type (`id`, `NSObject *`, etc.) auto-initialized to nil upon object allocation or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Objective-C guarantee the initialization of interface member data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533209/does-objective-c-guarantee-the-initialization-of-interface-member-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see [The Objective C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html) documentation on Apple's site.

> The alloc and allocWithZone: methods initialize a newly allocated object’s isa instance variable so that it points to the object’s class (the class object). All other instance variables are set to 0. Usually, an object needs to be more specifically initialized before it can be safely used.

Answer (score 2):

ivars are, but local variables aren't.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533209/does-objective-c-guarantee-the-initialization-of-interface-member-data)

Comment: @Joe: probably 'cause the C standard says so?

Comment: does `NSInteger x; NSLog(@"Int: %i", x);` count as reference?

Comment: Objective C is based on C, and C doesn't initialise them.  Objective C explicitly defines *ivars* as being initialised to `0`, but doesn't do the same for local variables.  Hence, standard C rules apply.  Or, in other words, what's your reference that they *are*?  :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's NSObject class reference doc says:

"The isa instance variable of the new instance is initialized to a data structure that describes the class; memory for all other instance variables is set to 0."

0 is the same as nil for a pointer.