# Do all object start with null (0x0) in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Objective-C guarantee the initialization of interface member data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533209/does-objective-c-guarantee-the-initialization-of-interface-member-data)

When I declare an object in the header (.h file) and do not assign any value to it. What will be it initial value?

```
@interface myObject: NSObject {
    NSString *instanceObject;
}

- (id)init 
{
    NSLog(@"The value of object is: %@", instanceObject);
    return [super init];
 }
```

This will show:

```
The value of object is: (null)
```

Can I assume all objects will start with `null=0x0` and never with garbage?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For Objects (like NSString*) yes, but for simple types like int and long u can't assume its a 0 by default.

and note, that when u release an object it doesn't become a nil by default, so if u send it something again later, U'll get a crash in ur app

*Edited spelling*

Comment: This is incorrect; _all_ ivars, regardless of type, are initialized to the appropriate 0 value by `alloc`.